# Error con código php para inserción en mysql

Tags: php, html

Quiero introducir datos en **mysql mediante php** y este es el código que tengo, el cual no funciona, ¿me podrían decir donde está el error?

Aquí esta el form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "romaper.dominio.com" method = post>
        <label for="id">Id</label>
        <input type="num" name="id"><br>
        <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
        <input type="text" name="cliente"><br>
        <label for="adv_date">Fecha del aviso: </label>
        <input type="datetime" name="adv_date"
            value="<?php
                    echo date("d/m/Y");?>"></br>
        <label for="cons_date">Elija fecha para la consulta: </label>
        <input type="date" name="cons_date"
        min="2022-01-01" max="2022-12-31"><br>
        <label for="observ">Detalles del problema</label><br>
        <textarea name="observ" rows ="8" cols="24"></textarea><br>
        <label for="estado">Estado</label>
        <input type="num" name="estado"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar aviso"><br>

    </form>
```

Y aquí mi código php

```
 <?php
include("conexion.php");

        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["cliente"];
        $adv_date = $_POST["adv_date"];
        $cons_date = $_POST["cons_date"];
        $observ = $_POST["observ"];
        $estado = $_POST["estado"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO tbavisos(id, cliente, adv_date, cons_date, observ, estado)
                VALUES('$id', '$name', '$adv_date', '$cons_date', '$observ', '$estado')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

        if($result == FALSE){
            echo "Wrong query";
        }
        else{
            echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
            echo "<table><tr><td>Código: $id</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_aviso: $adv_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_consulta: $cons_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Observaciones: $observ</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Estado de la consulta: $estado</td> </tr></table>" ;
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
```

Comment: ¿Esto que es?  `<form action = "romaper.dominio.com" method = post>`  Diria que eso es lo que tienes que revisar.  Quita los espacios entre los iguales a ver si sera eso:  `<form action="romaper.dominio.com" method="post">`

Comment: El error nos lo deberias decir tu, pues tienes acceso a el en tu log de errores, si es que lo hay. A simple vista, aparte de eso del `<form>` el resto pinta bien. Si no recibes ningun error solo te queda revisar la conexion a la base de datos y comprobar los campos de la tabla donde quieres insertarlos y sus tipos por si acaso algo no concuerda.

Comment: Es la url de mi servidor apache dónde devuelve los datos del php, de todas formas tampoco me funciona la inserción si lo redirijo al .php en cuestión

Comment: El caso es que no me aparece errorLog como tal porque no me dice que haya ningún error, simplemente devuelve wrong query y la inserción no se realiza

Comment: Pues pon un `echo $query;` y mira lo que sale. Si lo ves bien lo pegas en el phpmyadmin y lo intentas a mano, a ver si mysql te devuelve algun error

Comment: @rpaillao Si llega a ejecutar el script da igual lo que haya puesto en el action, le esta funcionando, supongo que lo ha modificado para el ejemplo de codigo de la pregunta

Comment: Ya me funciona! Como decíais el fallo estaba en el form, no en el action sino en los "name", que no coincidian con los configurados en la query y en la bbdd.

Comment: Gracias al mysqli_error pude averiguar que el error era ese.

Comment: Intenta con este código para ver si tu problema es la conexión ``$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conexion));``, aunque creo que tu form action está mal definido, debería ser un archivo especifico y no un dominio.

Comment: Execelente, otra alma que hemos salvado.

Comment: Aunque seguramente no tenga nada a ver, en el input con name ```adv_date``` tiene un error. Haces ```value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y");?>">```. Debería ser ```value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>">```. Observa que cambié las comillas dobles que estaban en el paréntesis por comillas simples.

Comment: @Tupi Si miras la página de date() en la web del PHP verás que se pueden usar indistintamente tanto las comillas simples como las dobles:  https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: Hola @masterguru, gracias por comentar. He revisado la documentación y tienes razón, ¿pero no deberían ser comillas simples de todos modos? Es decir, el usuario usa dos pares de comillas dobles anidadas (en el value empieza y debería terminar al final del value). Por lo tanto, realmente está haciendo esto: ```value="<?php echo date("```d/m/Y```");?>">.```

Comment: @Tupi me has hecho dudar :-)  Pero no, piensa que primero se resuelve el php y lo que devuelve sera una cadena tipo `12/12/2022`, **sin** las comillas dobles.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por explicarlo @masterguru. ¡Ahora tiene sentido!